# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.' is that sql query error or something?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio.

**CustomerDetails.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomerDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="CustomerInfo.CustomerDetails" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 29%;
            height: 119px;
            margin-left: 51px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 240px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 240px;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h3 class="auto-style1">Enter Details</h3>
        </div>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <table align="center" class="auto-style2">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">User Name :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">Email :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="mail" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">Password :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="100px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Customer_Info_TableConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [cus_table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the exact output how I created the webpage design, and it allow me to enter the details in the field after I pressing the button I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

**CustomerDetails.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CustomerInfo
{
    public partial class CustomerDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Customer_Info_TableConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[cus_table]('" + name.Text+"','"+name.Text+"','"+mail.Text+"','"+password.Text+"')",con);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Information uploaded Successfully! :)";

            name.Text = "";
            mail.Text = "";
            password.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Customer_Info_TableConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-B44TBSQ;Initial Catalog=Customer_Info_Table;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cus_table]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [mail] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Never, ever, ever, construct an sql statement from user supplied strings. Always use parameter binding.

Comment: Suggestion: After fixing the bug, try setting a password that contains a single quote in it somewhere.

Comment: @Nisarg ah, the well known password of `fish'); delete from cus_table; --` (note for Raja: **do not enter this password**, it will break your db because of how insecure the code is)

Answer (score 5):

1. never ever concatenate values to create SQL (see: SQL injection); use parameters, ideally with a tool like dapper
2. it is *adviseable* to specify the column order when inserting to prevent ambiguities
3. never ever store passwords as text; hash them with salt for authentication (long boring but important topic), or use strong encryption if you're writing a password manager

This example uses [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) for convenience; note that Dapper also deals opening and closing the connection, parameter packing, and (when using `Query<T>` etc) parsing results into instances. All the boring bits of ADO.NET!

```cs
var pwHash = // ... not shown; something involving password.Text
             // note: you'd usually need to invent and store the "salt", too
conn.Execute(@"
    insert into [dbo].[cus_table] (name, mail, passwordHash)
    values (@name, @mail, @pwHash)",
    new {
        name = name.Text,
        mail = mail.Text,
        pwHash = pwHash
    });

Label1.Visible = true;
Label1.Text = "Information uploaded Successfully! :)";
```

Note: the above wont work directly because you have a `password` column not a `passwordHash` column. But importantly: your `password` column is just a thing that **should not exist**. I can't force you to fix it, but: please please do.

The *bad security* version would be something like:

```cs
conn.Execute(@"
    insert into [dbo].[cus_table] (name, mail, password)
    values (@name, @mail, @password)",
    new {
        name = name.Text,
        mail = mail.Text,
        password = password.Text // TODO: hash (for auth) or encrypt (pw manager)
    });
```

Comment: @RajaGopal as a "get it working" step, I've added a version at the bottom of my answer that doesn't worry about the hashing step

Comment: It would be beneficial to OP to actually identify WHY the code failed. In this case, the list of "values" that was concatenated into the insert query was interpreted as the column list. Another bad coding habit.